# android emulator provide black screen in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

i create android emulator in android studio but provide black screen after run and show in device running and i can run code and install successfully but still emulator provide black screen.
i try wide data, delete it and create new one, make it Cold Boot from AVD Manager.
but also don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved this issue for me : android studio > setting (or) preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools . i found Android Emulator, Android SDK platform, Android SDK Build tools (want update). and make sure intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (install). hope i help.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your new virtual device, try setting "Emulated Performance Graphics" to "Hardware".